# why my computer's resource exhausted while has lots of memory?

Tags: internet-explorer

My computer configuration is : WINDOWS XP, 2G memory,
I had a bad habit, when I browse a webpage I like, I will not close it, just let it live in my IE8, for I may want to read this page later!
So my IE always spend most of my memory. When there's 30 plus tab in my IE, and some word documents open, then if I click 'My Computer' desktop icon, the explorer sometimes don't show menu etc, Seems not enough resource, If I close some documents, the explorer back to normal. But when I use tool to see how much memory left, the tool shows 1G left,
Then what happened to my computer. Does anyone use web browser like my kind?

Comment: There are millions of people who use the same web browser as you.

Comment: Which Processor you using and what is your net speed

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you're running out of USER objects.  USER objects represent user interface elements like desktops, windows, menus, cursors and icons.  There are upper limits on the number of USER objects in Windows, and when you reach those limits, you will typically see strange behaviour, similar to what you describe.  You can use the freeware [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) from SysInternals/Microsoft to confirm that this is the problem and definitively identify the offending process.

Mark Russinovich has written [an excellent overview of USER and GDI objects](http://blogs.technet.com/b/markrussinovich/archive/2010/02/24/3315174.aspx) and their limits in Windows.

Unfortunately, even after you've confirmed that IE is causing the problem, the only solution will be to close IE, thus freeing up the USER resources, then run IE again.

As a long-term solution, I recommend using IE's Favorites feature to create shortcuts to the web sites you like.  You can organize your Favorites into a tree structure that makes it easy to group sites by task or topic.  That way you don't have to leave your favorite sites open in the browser all the time and you won't deplete your system's resources.

Answer (score 0):

Your Windows XP might not have enough Virtual Memory.

Press [WIN]+[PAUSE] key combo to get into "System Properties" window, then  select the "Advanced" tab. Then under the "Performance" section press the "Settings Button", the "Performance Options" window will pop up.

On the "Performance Options" Window select the "Advanced" tab... and then click on the button "Change" under the "Virtual memory" section, this will popup the "Virtual Memory" window.

Under the "Virtual Memory" window, in section "Paging file size for selected drive" make sure the option "System managed size" is selected and press the button "set" (if enabled).

Press "OK" buttons to close all the opened windows.

Note: The name of the windows/buttons might vary in your language.

Answer (score 0):

I am using Firefox and I have 22 websites in my Tab now and I don't face this issue. May be you are temporarily out of cache memory . You may make your IE Pages Work offline and Refresh them When you need them. so that they take less time and resource when you start your IE. Additionally this kind of Windows behavior is seen when you have less space in Windows installed drive. Make sure you have enough space in Windows drive.